# N-dimensional tori for integrable systems with bounded motion

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, integrable-systems

I am reading the book *Dynamics* by N. Rasband. In chapter 9, it is said that the phase space of an integrable system with bounded motion is described in a compact submanifold $M_{I_0}$ which has the topology of an *n-dimensional invariant tori*.

I understand it is named like that because each submanifold is labeled by an invariant $I_0$, and there are $n$ of these. What I still don't understand, is why a tori is the only topology that can be choosen.

I know that the *global coordinate mesh* must be one that does not contain any singlularities. Then, **is the tori the only topology that doesn't contain singularities? isn't there any counterexample for this? or it can be proven that a tori is really the only topology that can be choosen? (unicity)**